# How to identify if a smartphone is connected to computer?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, events, wpd

I have a smartphone (any operating system like iOS, Android or Windows 8), and as soon as I connect it to computer (through wire), I want my Windows Form Application to identify that a device is connected and it needs to tell me which device is connected (like "Android Device is Connected").

I searched for this, and identified and good way to do from this link [DriveDetector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program). It talks about overriding `WndProc`  and making use of `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message to identify if a device is inserted or removed.

I notice the `WndProc` overridden method is getting fired multiple times with the approach. I want to know if there is any better way to do it?

Comment: You only list 3 mobile operating systems. Are those the only ones you care about?

Comment: yes, as of now those are sufficient for me.